# DDEV is there a command to (re-)create an empty database?

Tags: database, ddev

I've dropped the default database `db` and was not able to restart DDEV anymore and got some errors about not-existing DB.

Used `ddev delete` to re-start.

Is there a command that just created default DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `ddev delete` or `ddev delete --omit-snapshot` is the normal way to delete the `db` database.

Second, if you *did* want to delete the default `db` database some other way, you could use `ddev mysql`. For example,

`ddev exec -s db 'mysql --database=mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE db;"'`

But mostly... don't delete the default database. Maybe you can explain why you'd want to do that. If you want to drop all tables in the database there are better ways to do that.

Comment: The DB was drop by another script. `ddev delete --omit-snapshot` worked for me, while `ddev exec` did not b/c ddev does not started.

Comment: thougt `ddev delete` does more then just delete db ... it worked for me, thanks.

Comment: `ddev delete` deletes the database and unregisters the project from `ddev list`.